# Automate pull requests between branches in VSTS

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I wanted to know if it is possible to automate pull requests between branches and make it a part of the release flow in Visual studio Team services?
E.g.: Let's say i want to push the changes from master to QA once the build succeeds or may be during the release.

Comment: Do you solve the issue with my solution?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is that you can create pull request through [Create a pull request REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests/pull-requests#create-a-pull-request) (could call it through PowerShell).

Simple workflow:

1. Create a Continuous Integration build definition (Build definition> Triggers> Enable Continuous Integration)
2. Add necessary information (e.g. branch name) to a file (e.g. txt) and publish to artifact
3. Create a Continuous Deployment release definition with previous build
4. Read necessary information for the file that in artifact and create a pull request through REST API

A blog about calling REST API through PowerShell: [Calling VSTS APIs with PowerShell](http://blog.devmatter.com/calling-vsts-apis-with-powershell/)